# Ubuntu 22.04 very slow on AMD EPYC 7302

Tags: 22.04, performance, amd-processor

I have install Ubuntu 22.04 on brand new Supermicro server (AMD EPYC 7302). Everything went good during installation but when I try to install or remove package and just stuck there for very long time, almost took 15 min to install something and remove something. CPU was going up so high and noticed bunch of zombie process in top command.

I didn't find anything interesting in logs or kernel exception (including dmesg).

I have installed same version of Ubuntu on `Intel` CPU and it works like butter very fast and smooth (even intel server is 5 year older).

clearly something is wrong with Ubuntu + AMD combination.

```
# uname -a
Linux os1-bos-ctrl01 5.15.0-88-generic #98-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 2 15:18:56 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

CPU

```
processor   : 63
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 23
model       : 49
model name  : AMD EPYC 7302 16-Core Processor
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x830107a
cpu MHz     : 1500.000
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 32
core id     : 29
cpu cores   : 16
apicid      : 187
initial apicid  : 187
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 16
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdpru wbnoinvd amd_ppin arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif v_spec_ctrl umip rdpid overflow_recov succor smca sme sev sev_es
bugs        : sysret_ss_attrs spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass retbleed smt_rsb srso
bogomips    : 5967.87
TLB size    : 3072 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13] [14]
```

grub

```
# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-88-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro
```

Comment: Hi @Satish. What's the disk performance on normal use?. I mean copying something within your drives?

Comment: I have Intel NvME disk.. This machine is brand new and 256G memory 25G nic. I don't think its disk or cpu speed. This is some kind of bug. after reboot machine running super fast.. but sometime its just damn slow..

Comment: I am running in legacy mode BIOS. Not sure if UEFI will help or not.